# Jenkins build failed with "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER"

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am new to Jenkins, Recently Server windows 2008 R2 is updated with some patching. Before that, Jenkins was working fine but now whenever I am deploying via Jenkins, I am getting following error.

Does it seem related to Permission?
But what type of permission and where do I need to give?

```
/C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /v:q /property:configuration=Dev /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://<URL>/MSDeploy.axd /p:DeployIisAppPath=DEV_BackAPI /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:Username=SYS_NAME\USER_PRODirectTest /p:Password=PASSWORD BACKAPI.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4253,5): msdeploy error ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER: Web deployment task failed. (Unable to perform the operation ("Delete Directory")  for the specified directory ("4_0_30319"). This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user credentials you are using. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\FA BEAPI - DEV\workspace\PRO.BACKAPI\PRO.BACKAPI.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4253,5): msdeploy error ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER:   Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.) [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\FA BEAPI - DEV\workspace\PRO.BACKAPI\Falck.BACKAPI.csproj]
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it seem related to Permission?

Yes, it does.

> but what type of permission and where do I need to give?

As in here, try and grant access to the site folder for

- `LOCAL SERVICE` because Web Management Service runs under this account
- and for `NETWORK SERVICE` because of Web Deployment Agent Service

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
so I will give permission by right click the website folder -> under security tab?

Comment: @Salikix Yes, you can start with that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Asp_client folder in the website project.
when I deleted it, it got work.

Thank you